# jQuery checkbox hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I have problem this work and all fine, but the checkbox not so good
if I mark `checkbox1` after reload it's mark the `checkbox2` and `checkbox1`. I must help to find how this work.

Save only the checkbox mark

```
$(function(){        
  $('#checkbox1')
    .prop('checked', localStorage.input === 'true')
    .on('change', function() {
      localStorage.input = this.checked;
      if (this.checked) {
        $('.column_category').show(0); //checked
      } else {
        $('.column_category').hide(0);
      }
    })
    .trigger('change');
});

$(function(){        
  $('#checkbox2')
    .prop('checked', localStorage.input === 'true')
    .on('change', function() {
      localStorage.input = this.checked;
      if (this.checked) {
        $('.column_sku').show(0); //checked
      } else {
        $('.column_sku').hide(0);
      }
    })
    .trigger('change');
});


<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Categories</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/><label for="cbxShowHide">SKU</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"/><label for="cbxShowHide">UPC</label>
```

Comment: Not the problem but you don't need a 0 inside show or hide methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/441s41mt/1/

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
  $(this).prop('checked', (localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('id')) === 'true') ? 'checked' : '')
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]')  
  .on('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), this.checked);
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    } else {
      $('.' + $(this).data('target')).hide();
    }
  })
  .trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" data-target="column_category"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Categories</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" data-target="column_sku"/><label for="cbxShowHide">SKU</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"/><label for="cbxShowHide">UPC</label>
```

First thing, please refer to `jsfiddle` as `localStorage` will nit work on `stackoverflow` snippet.

Use `data-target` in `checkbox` to refer classes.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hi
thanks this work perfect
i change the the type to class because this on page with a lot of checkbox

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you bind `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` to the same `input` field of `localStorage`. Maybe this can help:

```
$('#checkbox1')
  .prop('checked', localStorage.check1State=== 'true')
  .on('change', function() {
     localStorage.check1State = this.checked;
     if (this.checked) {
       $('.column_category').show(0); //checked
     } else {
       $('.column_category').hide(0);
     }
  })
  .trigger('change');
});
```

And something similar on second checkbox.

Comment: yes 
this start of somthing
it's work if i put for every checkbox this command
if have any idea maybe make it's small code , can be better

but thanks a lot... this help me